# Resampling in Impala Tables ... Group by segment of Time

Tags: sql, time, impala, resampling, qsqlquery

I have table in Impala in which I have data for every second. I would like to have data after every 5 minutes. Given Table :

```
Time  Data

2021-01-01 00:00:01 123

2021-01-01 00:00:02 145

2021-01-01 00:00:03 456

2021-01-01 00:00:04 698

2021-01-01 00:00:05 589
```

I require my output like this

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00 123

2021-01-01 00:05:00 458

2021-01-01 00:10:00 784
```

I know that in SQL it is quite easy by using the following code:

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 30
```

But when I try this in Impala then I am getting error:

```
select from_unixtime(ts DIV 1000) as NewTime, ts, unit, Temperature
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
where unit='Unit102'
and cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-16 00:00:00' and '2021-01-23 00:00:00'
group by from_unixtime(ts DIV 1000) DIV 30
```

Then I am getting the following Error:

***Arithmetic operation requires numeric operands: from_unixtime(ts DIV 1000) DIV 30***

Any idea that how can I achieve this in Impala.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you pls try below sql.
I extracted minutes( every 5th minute) and seconds (0th) and added them so i can choose 0th,5th,10th...  minutes. if the sum is 0 which means it will be always pick 5th minutes with 0 second.

```
select  ts, unit, Temperature
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
where unit='Unit102'
and cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-16 00:00:00' and '2021-01-23 00:00:00'
and mod(minute (ts),5)+ second(ts) =0
```

Now, your sql has some fundamental flaw in `from_unixtime` syntax, `DIV` input. `from_unixtime` this returns a string.
Pls let me know if above sql works for you.
EDIT : A generic solution -
Assume you create a new table with sampling interval - sample_interval column name si - values must be in seconds.

```
select  ts, unit, Temperature
FROM Sensor_Data.Table
Join sample_interval si 
where unit='Unit102'
and cast(ts/1000 as TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '2020-11-16 00:00:00' and '2021-01-23 00:00:00'
and 
case when si.si >60 then mod(minute (ts), floor(si.si,60) ) + mod (second(ts), mod(si.si,60)) -- floor(si.si,60) will give minutes and mod(si.si,60) will give reminder.
else mod (second(ts), si.si)
end =0
```

Comment: Thanks @Koushik Roy !!!
It solved the problem.
But I was looking for more generic solution where I can resample the data based on "seconds" or "minutes", etc.
This query is particular for "minute" and for "second" I have to write another one.
How can I generalize it ?

Comment: modified the answer, could you pls chk

Comment: are you sure that this query is correct ?
Are there some misisng brackets and Table names ?

Comment: As i said, i assumed you have a table named `sample_interval` with a INT column called `si`.  I dont have your table set to test this out, i think the brackets are ok. what err you are seeing?